# Why does crc32 say some of my files are 'BAD'?

Tags: filenames, checksum

I used `crc32` to compare some files with a backup of them. Out of 3556 files, 11 were reported as 'BAD' as in the following example:

```
9be46354        ./9836Feeding_the_dog_.mpeg   BAD 9be46354 != 9836Feed
```

However, the files are *not* bad, but for some reason `crc32` has compared the checksum it calculated with part of the filename.

I then tried an experiment:

```
$ echo 12345 > 9836Feeding_the_dog_.mpeg
$ crc32 9836Feeding_the_dog_.mpeg
261dafe6
```

So this time `crc32` appears not to have compared the checksum with the filename, and the file is not 'BAD'.

What is happening here? Does this happen to other checksums?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `crc32` executable that you are using is a Perl script distributed together with the `Archive::Zip` Perl module.

The `crc32` Perl script is quite short, and has this little thing in it:

```
if ( $file =~ /[^[:xdigit:]]([[:xdigit:]]{8})[^[:xdigit:]]/ ) {
    my $filenameCrc = $1;
    if ( lc($filenameCrc) eq lc($fileCrc) ) {
        print("\tOK")
    } else {
        print("\tBAD $fileCrc != $filenameCrc");
    }
}
```

That is, *if the pathname of the file* contains eight consecutive hexadecimal digits, preceded and followed by at least one non-hexadecimal digit, *this hexadecimal number* is compared with the CRC32 checksum of the file.

In your case, you're running `crc32` on `./9836Feeding_the_dog_.mpeg`.  This pathname contains some non-hexadecimal digits (`./`) followed by exactly eight hexadecimal digits (`9836Feed`) and then something non-hexadecimal again.  `9836Feed` is not the CRC32 checksum of the file, so it complains.

Example that triggers this behaviour that is "not BAD":

```
$ cat 261dafe6_file
12345
$ crc32 ./261dafe6_file
261dafe6        OK
```

Recreating your test, and provoking the "BAD" response by adding `./` in front of the pathname of the file:

```
$ echo 12345 >9836Feeding_the_dog_.mpeg
$ crc32 9836Feeding_the_dog_.mpeg
261dafe6

$ crc32 ./9836Feeding_the_dog_.mpeg
261dafe6        BAD 261dafe6 != 9836Feed
```

Since the `crc32` executable is undocumented, obviously somewhat quirky, and not widely used (I didn't know about it and had to track it down, but that may not say much) I would suggest using some other tool for calculating the checksums of files.  The `md5sum` tool from GNU coreutils is widely used, and on BSD systems you may use `md5`.  There are also utilities for calculating stronger hashes (SHA1, SHA256 and SHA512 and others are supported by readily available utilities).

---

(By "non-hexadecimal digit" I mean "something that is not a hexadecimal digit")

Comment: Thanks. Please can you explain why `crc32 ./9836Feeding_the_dog_.mpeg` results in `BAD...` but `crc32 9836Feeding_the_dog_.mpeg` doesn't?

Comment: @EmmaV The code of `crc32` takes the `./` at the start of the filename into account when finding the hexadecimal number in the in the filename.  Without `./`, the regular expression does not match (since the 8-digit hex number is then not preceded by a non-hex digit) so that piece of the code that I quoted is not triggered. It's silly, really. Use another tool if you're able to.

Comment: I'll change to `md5sum`.

Comment: Bug reported upstream https://github.com/redhotpenguin/perl-Archive-Zip/issues/97